# PostgreSQL Index performance gain/loss takes effect after a short amount of time

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, indexing

I have noticed that both when adding or removing indexes from my  PostgreSQL database, the effects ( increase and decrease in performance respectively ) take effect after 4-5 minutes. I do not do any server restart on the meanwhile.

Any idea why that happens ?

Comment: this has a higher chance of getting answered on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is it possible your CREATE|DROP INDEX statement is in a transaction which doesn't get COMMITed until several minutes later? For example, `psql -1 -f script.sql` would wrap the whole script execution in a transaction, so if the script made an index then did some more work that took a few minutes, the index wouldn't be visible to any other executions until the whole script completed. You also might get that behavior if AUTOCOMMIT is OFF in .psqlrc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably this happens because the auto-vacuum process kicks in and updates the statistics for those indexes (as a "side-effect").

Only if the statistics are up-to-date the planner can take full advantage of them.

Try to run a `analyze verbose your_table` the next time you add or remove an index on `your_table` and see if that immediately "activates" it. If so, then it's the updated statistics that cause this "delay"